# Loop iterator in html side

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this following code in the home.ts:

```
selected: any;
this.selected = [{"toto": ["test1", "test2", "test3"], "tata": ["test4", "test5", "test6"]}]
```

and this code in the home.html:

```
<ion-content>
    <div *ngFor="let select of selected">
        <ion-card>
            <p> toto: {{select.toto}}<p>
            <p> tata: {{select.tata}}<p>
        </ion-card>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

So this code display toto: test1, test2, test3 and same for the other.
What I want to have is the equivalent of this:

```
<ion-card>
    <p>toto: {{selected.toto[0]}}</p>
</ion-card>
<ion-card>
    <p>toto: {{selected.toto[1]}}</p>
</ion-card>
```

Is it possible to replace the 0 by a variable that increments? an iterator, or something that gives the same result ?
Am I forced to do this in the ts file?

Comment: test1,test2,test3,test4, etc in each card?

Comment: in each card I want test1, test4 then test2, test5 and finally test3, test6

Comment: do they have same number of tests? - `toto` and `tata`?

Comment: yes, they have the same length

Comment: ok..check my answer

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have the `ngFor` with `ion-card`.

```
<ion-content>
    <div *ngFor="let select of selected">
        <ion-card *ngFor = "let toto of select.toto;let i=index">
            <p> toto: {{toto}}</p>
            <p> tata: {{select.tata[i]}}</p>
        </ion-card>    
    </div>
</ion-content>
```